# grep in a searched pattern and replace if the pattern doesn't exist

Tags: shell, vim, replace, sed

I've a file in the following format:

```
========================================================
line1line1line1line1line1line1line1line1line1

line2-anything could be here

...anything again

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

========================================================

abc abc abc bacbk kjhhjkh

line2-anything could be here SOME_STRING

...anything again

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I want to search and replace the blocks (defined between `=====*` and `++++*`) with say `abc` in which `SOME_STRING` doesn't exist. for example, the above file would look like:

```
========================================================

abc

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

========================================================

abc abc abc bacbk kjhhjkh

line2-anything could be here SOME_STRING

...anything again

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

as block 1 doesn't have `SOME_STRING`.

I can get the block using the search pattern

```
========================================================\_.\{-\}++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

but then I want to grep the result of this pattern search and if grep returns 1 (no matches found), replace the block with `abc`.

Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep is not the right tool for this. Use awk like this:

```
awk 'c &&  $0 != "++++"{ l=l $0 RS }
     /====/{ print; c=1 } 
     c && $0 == "++++"{
       if (l ~ /SOME_STRING/)
          print l $0;
       else
          print "abc" RS $0;
       c=0;
       l=""
     }' file
```

PS: For showing you code I truncated `===================` and `++++++++++++++++` to length 4 in my code above.

**Explanation:**

```
/====/{ print; c=1 }    - If input matches "====" then print the line and set c=1
c && !($0 ~ /\+\+\+\+/) - If c=1 and input doesn't match "++++" then don't print but append 
                          current line into a buffer (l=l $0 RS)
c && $0 ~ /\+\+\+\+/ - If c=1 and input matches then execute below block:
   if (l ~ /SOME_STRING/) - if SOME_STRING is in buffer then print buffer + current line
   else                   - print abc + current line
   c=0;l=""               - reset our variables
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but is it not possible with sed or vim? I don't understand awk.

Comment: awk is pretty cryptic. Could you please outline your approach?! Without that, there's little learning in your canned solution.

Comment: @IngoKarkat: If awk is cryptic then sed will 10x more cryptic :P

Comment: @anubhava: Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly. I know basic commands of awk but couldn't understand the commands here. Can you please elaborate your code? Thanks again

Comment: Ok sure adding explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know how to achieve it with [vim](/questions/tagged/vim), so deleted the post to try with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

Content of `script.sed`:

```
## For all lines between these patterns...
/^====/,/^++++/ { 
    ## Add current line to "hold space"
    H   

    ## Process next one unless reach to end of range.
    /^++++/! { b } 

    ## Get content of "hold space"
    x   

    ## Remove leading newline added by previous "H" command.
    s/^\n//

    ## If not found the string, do the removal saving either
    ## header and footer.
    /SOME_STRING/! { 
        s/^\(=\+\n\).*\(\n+\+\)$/\1abc\2/ 
    }   

    ## Print and remove all content from both buffers.
    p   
    s/^.*$//
    x   
    s/^.*$//
}
```

Assuming following input file (`infile`):

```
========================================================
line1line1line1line1line1line1line1line1line1
line2-anything could be here
...anything again
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

========================================================
abc abc abc bacbk kjhhjkh
line2-anything could be here SOME_STRING
...anything again
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

========================================================
abc abc abc bacbk kjhhjkh
line2-anything could be here SOME_STRING
...anything again
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
========================================================
line1line1line1line1line1line1line1line1line1
line2-anything could be here
...anything again
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Run it like:

```
sed -nf script.sed infile
```

That yields:

```
========================================================
abc
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
========================================================
abc abc abc bacbk kjhhjkh
line2-anything could be here SOME_STRING
...anything again
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
========================================================
abc abc abc bacbk kjhhjkh
line2-anything could be here SOME_STRING
...anything again
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
========================================================
abc
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: I guess this would actually replace the blocks having string SOME_STRING to abc. I want to replace the blocks where SOME_STRING **doesn't exist**. operator [^some_char] works fine for a character but here I need "anything other than SOME_STRING"

Comment: @SaurabhDhir: Oh, it's true. Sorry. I will try to fix it.

Comment: @SaurabhDhir: I've tried with `sed` at the end instead `vim`. Seems easier for me that way.

Comment: Is it possible to do it with sed? I failed to write a pattern where I can do a "anything other than the string SOME_STRING". BTW Anubhava's solution using awk is working fine.

Comment: @SaurabhDhir: I don't know what do you mean. I already changed the answer with the `sed` solution.

Comment: Oops I am sorry I didn't see the updated post. Thanks a lot. Can you please explain the content of script.sed file?

Comment: @SaurabhDhir: Edited to add comments to the script.